# How does biometric authentication add protection to encryption schemes?

Tags: encryption, keys, authentication, passwords, password-based-encryption

I'm wondering since at least 2 offline password management services,Passkeep and Keepass both use biometric authentication in addition to the master password. You need to possess the physical device to login to those 2 services,but if the attacker already posseses the device how would biometric authentication protect the user from accessing the key and encrypted data or whatever sensitive data they might have?

[passkeep.pro](https://passkeep.pro)

[keepass](https://keepass.info/help/kb/yubikey.html)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the goal is not to *"protect the user from accessing the key"*.

The intend seems to be protecting the user having stored valuable credentials in a device from impersonation by an attacker having stolen the device.

Comment: so it would make sense to you to have a offline  password manager that requires both a master password and biometric authentication to access any personal data?

Comment: Fir high-security application, that makes some sense. One needs device AND password  AND biometric to use the credentials. Also, there might be a lower-security convenience mode where the device unlocks with password OR biometric device. Many mobile phones work that way.